# Cannot obtain reading from meter (Modbus)

Tags: programming, arduino-nano, c, sketch, modbus

I have a system in which I am taking readings from a meter and processing it through an Arduino Nano. My code looks as follows:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define SerialControl 7
#define RS485Tx HIGH
#define RS485Rx LOW

SoftwareSerial RS485Serial(11, 12);
uint8_t window[8]; // Initialising window of 8 bytes

byte SendKWh[] = { 0x01, 0x03, 0x40, 0x34, 0x00, 0x02, 0x90, 0x05 };

// 0x01: Meter Address, 0x03: Read Function Code, 0x40: Register Address Variable (Start address high bit)
// 0x34: Register Address Variable (Start address low bit)
// 0x00: Register Quantity (High Bit), 0x02: Register Quantity (Low Bit)
// 0x90: CRC check code (CRC code Low bit)
// 0x05: CRC check code (CRC code High bit)

void dumpWin() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    Serial.print(window[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void ReadRx() {
  // Sliding Window Implementation for reading data
  if(RS485Serial.available()) {
    uint8_t b = RS485Serial.read();
    dumpWin();
    // Slide the contents of the array down
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      window[i] = window[i+1];
    }
    window[7] = b; // Next frame inserted at the top of previous  
    if ((window[0] == 0x01) && (window[1] == 0x03) &&
      (window[2] == 0x40) && (window[3] == 0x34)) {
      // Doing something with window[4] and window[5] here
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(SerialControl, OUTPUT);
  RS485Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
  static uint32_t ts = millis();
  if (millis() - ts >= 2000) {
    ts = millis();
    digitalWrite(SerialControl, RS485Tx);
    RS485Serial.write(SendKWh, sizeof(SendKWh));
    RS485Serial.flush();
    digitalWrite(SerialControl, RS485Rx);
    RS485Serial.listen();
  }
  ReadRx();
}
```

The `ReadRx()` is behaving odd and `dumpWin()` is giving `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` output. I have been trying but I'm not able to figure out where am I going wrong. Your help is appreciated!

EDIT 2: I changed the code as suggested by @Majenko but still `window[]` O/P is `0` for all. I am not able to understand as to why it is not able to read the values from `RS485Serial`.

Comment: Don't have all those delays. You don't want any delays anywhere.

Comment: Delay in `ReadRx` after `digitalWrite` ?

Comment: ReadRX only reads one byte. It needs to be run repeatedly and fast. Leave the rs485 in RX mode all the time except when you specifically want to transmit.

Comment: I removed `delay(1500)` and still the O/P for `dumpWin()` remains `0` for all.

Comment: Is there anything wrong in this statement `RS485Serial.write(SendKWh, sizeof(SendKWh));`

Comment: I think your whole method of working is wrong. In loop you should have a bit of code that decides if it's time to send. That then switches to send mode, sends, then switches back to read mode. Then all that is left in loop is the reading function, which just reads, adds to the array, and processes if it matches. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop thinking quite so linearly. You are working with asynchronous systems, so your code has to be asynchronous too.

Something more like this:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define SerialControl 7

#define RS485Tx HIGH
#define RS485Rx LOW


SoftwareSerial RS485Serial(11, 12);

byte SendKWh[] = { 0x01, 0x03, 0x40, 0x34, 0x00, 0x02, 0x90, 0x05 };

// 0x01: Meter Address, 0x03: Read Function Code, 0x40: Register Address Variable (Start address high bit)
// 0x34: Register Address Variable (Start address low bit)
// 0x00: Register Quantity (High Bit), 0x02: Register Quantity (Low Bit)
// 0x90: CRC check code (CRC code Low bit)
// 0x05: CRC check code (CRC code High bit)

uint8_t window[8]; // Initialising window of 8 bytes

void dumpWin() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    Serial.print(window[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void ReadRx() {
  if(RS485Serial.available()) {
    uint8_t b = RS485Serial.read();
    dumpWin();
    // Slide the contents of the array down
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      window[i] = window[i+1];
    }

    window[7] = b; // Next frame inserted at the top of previous  

    if ((window[0] == 0x01) && (window[1] == 0x03) &&
        (window[2] == 0x40) && (window[3] == 0x34)) {
          // Doing something with window[4] and window[5] here
    }
  }
}



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(SerialControl, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SerialControl, RS485Rx);
  RS485Serial.begin(9600); 

}

void loop() {
  static uint32_t ts = millis();

  if (millis() - ts >= 2000) {
      ts = millis();
      digitalWrite(SerialControl, RS485Tx);
      RS485Serial.write(SendKWh, sizeof(SendKWh));
      RS485Serial.flush();
      digitalWrite(SerialControl, RS485Rx);
      RS485Serial.listen();
  }

  ReadRx();
}
```

Notice how I use `millis()` to send the command every 2 seconds asynchronously (i.e., without `delay()`). The RS485 is kept in READ mode *except for the brief moment while you send*. Also note the use of `flush()`  to wait until the last symbol has been transmitted by the UART (software in this case) interface. It's important, otherwise you may cut off the transmission part way through (I don't think it's such a problem with SoftwareSerial, but with a hardware UART missing it out would be fatal).

The reading just reads one character and returns to the loop. Each iteration through the loop will (if a character is available) read just one character. Only when all 8 have been received and the contents of the window match up can you process anything (which you would put in place of the comment).

This method also leaves you free to implement other things in `loop()`, as long as they don't use `delay()` as well.